# How do I show an image using a relative or external url?

Tags: theming, entities, nodes, media, feeds

Seems like a simple issue but can't find a simple solution.

Basically I have the feeds module populating a content type from another database which has relative URLS of images. ie. `/images/image1.jpg`

I'm storing this value in a text field type.

Is there a way to easily translate the output of this field into `<img src="$value">` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, assuming Drupal 7, you can create your own field formatter for this in a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function YOURMODULE_field_formatter_info() {

  $info = array();

  $info['image_source_formatter'] = array(
    'label' => t('Image Source Formatter'),
    'description' => t('Display the image sourced in this field.'),
    'field types' => array('text'),
  );

  return $info;

}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function YOURMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {

    case 'image_source_formatter':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $element[$delta] = array(
          '#theme' => 'image',
          '#path' => $item['safe_value'], // you can also set '#height', '#width', '#alt', '#title' and '#attributes' here as well, see theme_image() for more details
        );
      }
      break;

  }

  return $element;

}
```

Clear your caches to be on the safe side, and then you can use this new field formatter for this field, eg, you can go to the Manage Display in your Content Type and select this:

[image]

for the plain text field and instead of outputting the text, it will theme the text as the path to an image.

In this field, you can have `sites/default/files/foo.jpg` if you want and it will source it locally, or you can have `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.jpg` and that'll work as well, as this will call [theme('image', $variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) with the path set to the value of this field.

ADDITION:  The [URL Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/url_formatter) and [Simple Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter) modules appear to do this for you if you don't want to create your own custom module.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be overwritting the field template

field-name-[field_name].tpl.php

You can then just simply add your markup

Example:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><img src="<?php print render($item); ?>" /></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The $items array provides an array of information for that item and uses render to render the output.  See the field template in the drupal api for more information
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7

If you are using Display suite https://drupal.org/project/ds then you can create a custom field  to output that value alongside the token module.  See this blog post for more details on that: http://www.elevatedthird.com/blog/using-custom-fields-display-suite-drupal-7